# c# latin1_swedish_ci to unicode

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySQL database with `latin1_swedish_ci` and when I'm trying to select something, select returns strings like this:

```
áƒ¢áƒáƒ‘áƒ˜ áƒ›áƒáƒ™áƒ’áƒ£áƒáƒ˜áƒ áƒ˜, áƒ™áƒ˜áƒ áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ”áƒœ áƒ“áƒáƒœáƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ˜, áƒ¯áƒ”áƒ˜áƒ›áƒ¡ áƒ¤áƒ áƒáƒœáƒ™áƒ
```

Here is my code:

```
string db = "server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;password=xxx;charset=utf8;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(db);
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SET NAMES utf8; SELECT * FROM `xxx`", con);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
     string source = reader.GetString("xxx");
     byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
     byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, utf8Bytes);
     string uf8converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBytes);    
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: do you have another database management system, such as phpMyadmin or mysql-workbench?. Maybe the data is saved in a wrong collation.

Comment: Note: collation != encoding.

Comment: database, table and column is in latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @Jaztingo did you check the data stored in ddbb?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a year old, but I had the same problem and found a solution:

```
string source = reader.GetString("xxx");
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] data = enc.GetBytes(source);
string uf8converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

The *latin1_swedish_ci* is codified as *Western European* (not ASCII), so for the result we hardcode the bytes in UTF8 :)